# List of Helpful Websites for Beginning Collectors

Tags: shopping

I recently wandered into my father's basement where my brother and I used to have our "game room" setup. I stumbled across a massive amount of LEGO that we had collected over the years.  Since then, I've had the urge to get back into LEGO, taking a more adult approach at collecting them.

I was wondering if there were additional sites besides the one's I've found that may shed some light for a beginning collector.  Also, feel free to include any tips that you think may be beneficial in this quest! Here are the list of sites I've come across:

- http://www.lugnet.com/
- http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Wiki
- http://www.brickset.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On top of the already mentioned:

1. http://www.lugnet.com/
2. http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Wiki
3. http://www.brickset.com/
4. http://www.peeron.com - Large set database and instruction scan library
5. http://www.bricklink.com - Lego marketplace selling millions of used and new parts and sets. This is also a nice reference for information and
   inventories related to old sets.

I personnally use the following ones as well:

1. http://www.brickfactory.info/ - Online collection of Lego Sets instructions
2. http://rebrickable.com/ - Site allowing you to see what other Lego set you can build from your existing collection

After that, it all comes down to forums and more specialized websites that directly depend on your area of interest (sci-fi, military, castle...), your language, and your location.

Answer (score 3):

On top of the resources that you listed, I have found these two sites to be incredibly useful:

1. [peeron.com](http://peeron.com) - Large set database and instruction scan library
2. [bricklink.com](http://bricklink.com) - Lego marketplace selling millions of used and new parts and sets. This is also a nice reference for information and inventories related to old sets.

It's not a site, but if you don't mind books, I would recommend [The Cult of Lego](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593273916) by John Baichtal.

You also might be interested in finding a LUG (Lego users group) near you. Here's a [map](http://www.lugnet.com/map/).